# Switch wiring - strange multimeter readings

Tags: dimmer-switch, replacement, voltage, multimeter

I'm about to replace a dimmer switch in my house (UK - Single Phase) and every wire in the backbox is red, while I've tested and identified each (live in, live out, neutral in, neutral out, neutral to light and switched live).  I was seeing something strange when testing with my multi-meter...earth-live 240v - ok, earth-neutral 0v - ok, live-neutral 115v.  The latter starts around 180v and settles down @ 115v while I'm measuring.  Any ideas what would cause that?  Bad multi-meter?

Comment: High-impedance digital multimeters can pick up voltage from adjacent wires. They are not appropriate tools for such measurement, unless you put a load resistor, perhaps 200,000 ohms, across the meter's leads.

Comment: You could say that, it's a "defect" in *almost all* DVMs.  Search our system for questions about "phantom voltage", that's what you're dealing with  here, and this question is a duplicate of any of those.